# Importing large data to postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I recently dual booted my system by installing Ubuntu over Windows. Now I have to import a file in postgresql , which is stored in host file system. The host filesystem has 190 GB of space. But when I log into postgres as sudo su postgres, it would take me into root filesystem(the default postgres folder) and query would be executed in that. Now my data set is of 3 GB and after sometime query would return 'OUT of disk space' as the root filesystem is of 3.5-4 GB. So it would be great if anyone can suggest solution to this? . Do I need to change default folder of postgres?

Thanks
Ravinder

Comment: You can try create a `tablespace` on different path/filesystem/drive and move/ your tables there. But if you use NTFS from Ubuntu for postgres DB - you may have problems with DB performance and stability.

Comment: Or you can just expand the disc partition used by Ubuntu.

Comment: I think the OP just means that uid=postgres does not have a home directory. (it does not need one, but it's nice to have one) BTW: disk space is not restricted by user or directory (unless you have quote anabled) It is restricted by the mounted filesystems. Maybe you could add the output of `df -k` to your post?

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      3.9G  2.0G  1.7G  54% /
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           773M  864K  772M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  156K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda6       196G   51G  145G  26% /host
/dev/loop1      3.9G  2.0G  1.7G  55% /usr
/dev/loop2      3.9G  3.7G   43M  99% /h

Comment: I think we have to increase the size of /usr or /h file system. Can anyone please explain how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a new file on host, which I'd configure as a second hard drive image for your Ubuntu. And I'd use this drive to create partition there and mount it where the PGDATA directory would be.

Comment: can you please explain more? I am new to Linux....how to configure second hard drive image?